# How to make utc field in dto of java on LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I made a normal api using spring boot as below.

```
@PostMapping("/lecture")
public ResponseEntity<Map> createLecture(@RequestBody @Valid LectureDto lectureDto, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    CustomUser user = null;
    if (null != securityContext.getAuthentication()) {
        user = (CustomUser) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error");
    }

    lectureService.createLecture(lectureDto, user.getId());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpCustomResponse.ok(null));
}
```

And I made a dto for this.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LectureDto {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone = "UTC")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime lectureDate;
}
```

But my goal is I want to make ISO 8601 UTC DTO on LocalDateTime.
For example, "2021-12-10T19:00:00.000Z" only this string can be put. 
But my JsonFormat doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` does not have any information about the time zone or offset, for that, use a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @deHaar Thank you! I sovled by using OffsetDateTime!

Comment: Good ;-) You're welcome...